Is a Voltage Sensitive Relay (VSR) inherently flawed?
A VSR is described by Jaycar:

This device will allow two batteries to be charged from your engine alternator at the same time. When your engine is on and the start battery is sufficiently charged the isolator kit will begin charging the second (auxiliary) battery simultaneously. When the voltage of the start battery drops (i.e.. the engine is stopped) the isolator kit disengages from charging the auxiliary battery. This isolates the start battery and eliminates the possibility of draining it, ensuring that you always have enough charge to start your engine.

I have purchased one from a different source, for my small campervan, which looks identical and has identical specifications. 
There are three connections on the back: two large terminals (bolts) and a flying ground wire. It's potted so effectively a three terminal "black box". Inside is a relay which bridges the two bolts after the "Cut In" voltage is exceeded. If the relay is open the resistance between the two bolts is Open by my Fluke meter. Interestingly it doesn't appear to matter which terminal I connect my adjustable PSU - both are monitored by the internal circuit. In addition to the hysteresis noted on the label there is internal timing circuitry gives several seconds of delay between crossing a threshold and the relay closing or opening.
The quiescent current is 10.5mA which I am happy with however when energised the current increases to an large 310mA.
So I'm anticipating that when installed the VSR will close once the starter battery voltage exceeds 13.3V and allow the auxiliary battery to charge to 13.7V (it's float voltage) or more (I measure 14.2V on my van's cigarette lighter socket when driving). However, when the engine is switched off the VSR will remain closed until it and any loads have discharged both batteries by several percent to 12.8V. That seems like an inherent flaw in this device yet they seem to be commonly available so presumably work OK. So are VSRs flawed or is my one faulty or is my reasoning wrong?

Can you clarify why you think this is a flaw? An appropriately sized lead-acid battery at 12.8V shouldn't have any trouble starting your van's engine.
